# On dropdown select show the input value in different DIV

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show

Hi I have a function that, when checked, shows the input value in a different DIV. But my next obstacle is to show/hide the value based on a dropdown. When an item is selected in a drop-down, it shows, and when it is unselected, it hides. Any help would be great.

Heres the radio show/hide

```
<script>
            function selectInt(cb) {
                var x = cb.checked ? cb.value : '';
                document.getElementById("interior").innerHTML = x;

            }
        </script>

<p id="acc" class="font-medium text-white"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="drop">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option> 
</select>
```

Now just get the change event and toggle a class which handles the visibility.

```
const dropElem = document.querySelector("#drop");

dropElem.addEventListener("change", function(){
  if(dropElem.value == "a"){  SOMEELEMEMENT.classList.toggle("visibilityClass")};
});
```